# Why can't Innermost stable circular orbit ($R_\text{ISCO}$) of a spinning black hole be zero?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, singularities

For a non spinning black holes, $R_\text{ISCO}$ is 3 times the Schwarzschild radius. And for a spinning black holes $R$  decreases. That means as long as the black hole is spinning fast enough, $R_\text{ISCO}$ can go on decreasing. My question is what prevents $R_\text{ISCO}$ to be zero?

Answer (score 2):

For a non-extremal ($|a| < M$) Kerr black hole the innermost stable circular orbit (and in fact any circular orbit) has to be outside the outer event horizon $r_{+} = M+\sqrt{M^2-a^2}$, because insider the outer horizon any timelike curve would need to have strictly decreasing (or strictly increasing) $r$ coordinate, and therefore could never form a circular (i.e. $r$ is constant) orbit, stable or otherwise. Consequently, we find that $r_{ISCO} > r_{+} > M$.

In practice it turns out that actually $r_{ISCO} \to r_{+}$ in the limit $a\to M$.

(note $G=c=1$)

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question was if an extremal black hole is theoretically possible. And from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_black_hole, it looks like it is.

Comment: @bitsabhi An extremal Kerr black hole would still have $r_{ISCO} = r_{+} = M>0$

Comment: @bitsabhi Although extremal Kerr black holes are theoretically solutions to the Einstein equations, the third law of black hole thermodynamics posits that they would be impossible to form in a physical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For rotating black-hole the [innermost stable circular orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit) given by
$$r_{ms}=\frac{GM}{c^2}(3+Z_2\pm \sqrt{(3-Z_1)(3+Z_1+2Z_2)}\leq 4.5R_S$$
The ISCO always lies outside the event-horizon of the black hole. If it's lie inside that means, it doesn't have any meaning (Since motion inside the event-horizon is not defined).